# Google API credentials refresh failed

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, credentials

It's part of my code:

```
 if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
                with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                    creds = pickle.load(token)
            if not creds or not creds.valid:
                if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
```

If creds expired it must be refresh. On Windows this part works, but on Linux I get an error (on the last string):

```
('invalid_scope: Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[a, c, d, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., /, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, w, :]}', '{\n  "error": "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description": "Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid\\u003d[a, c, d, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., /, o, p, r, s, t, u, v, w, :]}",\n  "error_uri": "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"\n}')
```

Comment: What scopes are you requesting and in where do you request them?

Comment: "scopes": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
for downloading files

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @JoséLuis, I used service account

Answer (score 16):

I am a python beginner and I had a similar problem. I edited https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python to be able to create events. I changed line with scope to:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
```

At first, my app works well, but then it is strange. Next day, it crashed and I have to delete token to be able to run the app again. When I run it I have to allow access (via opened browser) again. Then it works well, but next day again not;)

The problem is that the token expires in 3600s. That is the reason for the strange behaviour. When the token expires, it runs code for refresh existing token (`creds.refresh(Request())`), but on Windows I get an error:

```
RefreshError('invalid_scope: Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[a, c, d, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., n, /, o, p, r, s, t, u, w, :]}', '{\n  "error": "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description": "Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid\\u003d[a, c, d, e, g, h, i, l, m, ., n, /, o, p, r, s, t, u, w, :]}",\n  "error_uri": "http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html"\n}'),)
```

and app crash. From the error message I was confused.

When you delete token.pickle, it requires an autorization via browser again and after that the app works for another 3600s;) Many hours I was searching where is the problem.

Finally I found it. It should be:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
```

there were missing **[** and **]** brackets!!! It was causing the mentioned error.

*Now it works for me.*

Tip: when you want to test your app if the expiration and token refresh works, you can simply change the system clock to some future date.

Comment: Fantastic - this was killing me. Thanks for describing problem and solution so well.

Answer (score 1):

I been able to reproduce the error, I believe the problem will be solved if you declare the scopes as follow:

```
"scopes": "https://googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

instead of

```
"scopes": "googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

It should certainly work both ways, but it does not.

Please, let me know if this solves it.

Comment: I got here because I get the same error. I am using the https protocol for my scope. For me, it works fine if I run from the command line. When I schedule it to run in cron, it fails with that error message and then no longer works from the command line. In my cron job I'm source the `.bashrc` for the user and activating the virtualenv for my python job, and changing to the correct directory.

Comment: Hi @RobWilson , open a new question with details about what is going on, I’ll try to assist

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't find where I had put this comment. I have since gotten it working by removing the picl file a few more times and eventually one got created that worked when cron used it. I made no code changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the proper scopes to authorie the request. you might want to consider following Googles tutorial first.

## [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm following the same tutorial and getting `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', '{\n  "error": "deleted_client",\n  "error_description": "The OAuth client was deleted."\n}')
`

Comment: deleted_client means that the client in the Google developer console you created was deleted.  Go create a new one and use that client secrets file in your project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer, which I bet is the real cause of @jonrsharpe's issue. For what it's worth, one cause of the error posted above is setting SCOPES to be a scalar string, instead of a list of strings. Some older quickstart examples floating around do that, and the API no longer supports it.